# Download Image attached using Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Is there a way to make the users download the images attached using paperclip?

I just made a link like this:

```
link_to 'imagename', image.attachment.url
```

But this makes the browser open the image. I want the browser to ask the user to save the image. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Never done this before, but this might help: http://therailsway.com/2009/2/22/file-downloads-done-right

Comment: Exact replicate [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756416/rails-link-to-to-download-an-image-immediately-instead-of-opening-it-in-the-bro)

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to sending a file you can find all information in here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Streaming.html There are most important cuts:

Simple download:

```
send_file '/path/to.zip'
```

Show a JPEG in the browser:

```
send_file '/path/to.jpeg', :type => 'image/jpeg', :disposition => 'inline'
```

Show a 404 page in the browser:

```
send_file '/path/to/404.html', :type => 'text/html; charset=utf-8', :status => 404
```

to use one of this option you have to create a new action in controller like this:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def download_file
    send_file image.attachment.path
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution using the HTML5 download attribute

```
<%= link_to image.name, image.attachment.url, download: image.attachment.original_filename %>
```