# Rails 'link_to' to Download An Image Immediately Instead of Opening it in the Browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, download, link-to

I have a link_to Rails helper that downloads a wallpaper when clicked. But the image is loading in the browser instead of being downloaded immediately.

```
<%= link_to "1920x1080", @download.wallpapers[1].wallpaper.url %>
```

But at the same time I have a link_to Rails helper that downloads a screensaver of .exe format but here it works as inteded: file being downloaded immediately.

```
<%= link_to "720p", @download.screensavers.first.screensaver.url %>
```

What should I add or do so that the images will not be opened in the browser but instead be downloaded immediately?

Thanks!

Comment: Fairly certain this is a browser specific issue, not a web-framework issue. You can't view an EXE in a browser, but you can view an image.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Generally, the cleanest way to do this is to set the appropriate header when sending the image:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=&lt;file name.ext&gt;
```

The send_file method will allow you to set this header appropriately if you're serving the file from the filesystem:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Streaming.html#method-i-send_file

If the file is stored in your database, you can use send_data instead:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Streaming.html#method-i-send_data

Answer (score 43):

There is an easier way to do this with the [HTML5 download attribute](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2011/08/Downloading-resources-in-HTML5-a-download?hl=en).

```
<%= link_to 'Download existing avatar', @user.avatar(:original), download: "User_#{@user.id}_avatar" %>
```

Comment: This should most definitely be the accepted answer now.

Comment: Is there a way to not change the filename and still add the download attribute?

Comment: Yes,  [according to the spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download) this attribute's value is optional - without it the browser will suggest a file name.

Answer (score 14):

Instead of putting the link of the image in your tag, you can handle it in your controller.  And then in your controller you can do something like

```
send_file @download.wallpapers[1].wallpaper.url, :type => 'image/jpeg', :disposition => 'attachment'
```

Read [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Streaming.html#method-i-send_file)

Comment: For me it only worked with send_data: send_data image.url, :type => 'image/jpg', :disposition => 'attachment' being url a string " http:// url.com " for example

Answer (score 8):

Rails 3 / 4:

in routes:

```
get "home/download_pdf"
```

in controller:

```
def download_pdf
  send_file(
    "#{Rails.root}/public/your_file.pdf",
    filename: "your_custom_file_name.pdf",
    type: "application/pdf"
  )
end
```

in view:

```
<%= link_to 'Download PDF', home_download_pdf_url %>
```

Comment: What if the link is generated in .each iteration, and file name is dynamic.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple solution using the HTML5 download attribute with paperclip

```
<%= link_to item.name, item.asset.url, download: item.asset.original_filename %>
```