# Rails, paperclip and s3, prompt download or view images?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, paperclip

So i got successfully working Paperclip and S3 uploading in RoR 3, but it turns out that some images are prompted to download and others can be viewed in the browser. What determines this behaviour?

Comment: I believe the assets pipeline is what determines this behavior.

Comment: Right, then how to properly take control of the default action?

Comment: Where do they get called to be prompted/displayed in your app?

Comment: In the show page of my model, i have got a gallery. When i click in some images the browser navigates to the image url and displays it, some other are just prompted to download.

Comment: facing the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of this could be browser-specific behavior based upon the MIME file type that the server is sending your browser. .png files are most often the culprit for forced download. [See this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097781/chrome-downloads-png-image-links-i-want-them-to-open-for-viewing-in-a-new-tab) about the issues between IE uploads, old MIME types, etc.

If it is inconsistent on the type of picture, [there is a way you can force a file to be downloaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527713/force-browser-to-download-image-files-on-click), but no good way to force an image to be viewed in the browser.

Edit: I know that the forced download isn't rails specific, so [here is the rails-specific version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14406082/paperclip-force-download)

Answer (score 1):

Is one of the following helps you?

[Paperclip Force Download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14406082/paperclip-force-download)

[Rails 'link_to' to Download An Image Immediately Instead of Opening it in the Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756416/rails-link-to-to-download-an-image-immediately-instead-of-opening-it-in-the-br)

Both of them says to send the file to the browser as attachment.