# Getting gibberish while returning image from php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, dynamic-image-generation

I am using this code to generate barcode and i want to display it using ajax

```
<?php

require('class/BCGColor.php');
require('class/BCGDrawing.php');
require('class/BCGean8.barcode.php');

$font = new BCGFontFile('font/Arial.ttf', 18);
$color_black = new BCGColor(0, 0, 0);
$color_white = new BCGColor(255, 255, 255);

// Barcode Part
$code = new BCGean8();
$code->setScale(2);
$code->setThickness(30);
$code->setForegroundColor($color_black);
$code->setBackgroundColor($color_white);
$code->setFont($font);
$code->parse($_GET['code']);

// Drawing Part
$drawing = new BCGDrawing( '' , $color_white);
$drawing->setBarcode($code);
$drawing->draw();

header('Content-Type: image/png');

$drawing->finish(BCGDrawing::IMG_FORMAT_PNG);

?>
```

and this is my html and js

```
<img src="" id="my_image" />
<a href="gen_barcode.php?code=1234567">Click</a>
```

```js
$('a').on('click', function (e){
    $.ajax({
        url: "gen_barcode.php",
        type: 'GET',
        data: { code: '1234567' },
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log(data)
            $('#my_image').attr('src', data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(data)
        },
    })
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

I am getting some gibberish odd looking string from server. How can i correct it.
What am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the `src` of the image to the actual data of the image.  The `src` should be set to the URL of the image, rather than its content.  Instead, set it to the url of the page generating the data:

```
$('a').on('click', function (e){
    $('#my_image').attr('src', 'gen_barcode.php?code=1234567');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Ok thanks it works, now how can i implement when someone clicks download the image

Comment: @Cody If you have another question, feel free to ask another one - comments aren't the place to do so.  Though it sounds like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527713/force-browser-to-download-image-files-on-click)'s answers may answer it (ie use the `download` attribute).

Comment: thanks for response i am getting the image now, but tell me how download it when i click it. Most of the code is same that's why not asking another question. Thanks