# jQuery save image on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I heed to save image on click and for this purpose I use `download` attribute

```
<a href="http://mysite.ru/userfiles/certificate_2.png" class="download-certificate-link" data-title="certificate.png" download="certificate.png">Download</a>
```

and also I would like to add script for browsers which don't support HTML5 `download` attribute

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
if (typeof a.download == "undefined") {
    $('body').on('click', '.download-certificate-link', function(){
        $(this).attr('href').download;
        return false;
    });
}
```

but this script doesn't work. What's wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: `$(this).attr('href').download;` is supposed to do what? An attribute is a string and you are accessing a property?

Comment: I've tried to repeat something like that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527713/force-browser-to-download-image-files-on-click

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.download-certificate-link').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);        
        $this.wrap('<a href="' + $this.attr('src') + '" download />')
    });
});
```

[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/MW9E4/76/)

Comment: I don't need to add another `a` tag, I've already have one, and I search a solution for browsers which don't support HTML5 `download` attribute.

Comment: You are right it is not supported with safari except of that this is working with all latest browsers.