# Uploading and displaying images

Tags: javascript, php, html

Right now I am coding an website that will be used to upload and download images. I have an function that will upload the files but I don't how how to read how many there are in the folder and how to execute the createElement for each. All help is welcome...

Comment: Your problem and statement is unclear. Please work on your English.

Comment: When someone uploads a file, store the path in a database and read from the database all the uploads. Then you can construct a list of the images on your web dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

count images in your folder

```
$directory = '/var/www/ajaxform/';
$files = glob($directory . '*.jpg');

if ( $files !== false )
{
 $filecount = count( $files );
 echo $filecount;
}
else
{
 echo 0;
}
```

Comment: With the addition of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527713/force-browser-to-download-image-files-on-click) and you showing how to loop over the collection of `jpg` files (`foreach ($files as $filename) { ... }`), should make your example a complete solution. But still good enough for an upvote

Comment: Thanks helped me very much!