# HTML 5 canvas not showing certain parts when toDataUrl

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, google-visualization

I am making a chart in google chart and then converting that into an image using `.getImageURI()`.

This result is then passed as a parameter in a `onClick()` event in a button. When the user presses a button the chart gets added to a canvas along with some about the image, such as what is being plotted any dates.

However when ever I convert this image to a png and get the user to download it using `var dt = c.toDataURL('image/png');` then `window.open(dt);` all I get is the text I added.

Also when I make it into a jpeg and use the same methods if I add it as a `<img>` tag in my page it all shows up, chart and text. But when I try to download it just the chart downloads.

I don't mind either file type, I just want to download the image with the text.

This is my call to get the button with the google chart data url:

`var image = stockChart.getChart().getImageURI();`

`document.getElementById('png').innerHTML = '<button onClick="turnToImage(\''+image+'\', \''+$('#totalNumber').html()+'\')">Get Image</button>';`

Then the `turnToImage()` function that gathers relevent information and adds some text and the google chart to a canvas:

```
function turnToImage(chart, totalNum) {
    var pound = '\u00A3';
    var width = $(document).width();
    var height = $(document).height();
    var total = "Total: "+pound+totalNum;
    channels3 = channels2.substring(0, channels2.length - 1);
    var canvasText = total + " | Type: " + allNone + " | Channels: " + channels3 + " | Grouped By: " + grouping + " | Cumulative: " + cumulative + " | Dates: " + startDate + " - " + endDate;

    var canvas = '<canvas id="chartImage" width="'+width+'" height="'+height+'"></canvas>';
    $("#canvasHolder").html(canvas);

    var c = document.getElementById("chartImage");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.font = "15px Helvetica";

    img = new Image();
    img.src = chart;
    img.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 20);
    }
    ctx.fillText(canvasText, 10, 15);

    var dt = c.toDataURL('image/png');

    window.open(dt);

    $("#canvasHolder").html("<img src='"+dt+"'>");
}
```

Comment: Is there more information I can provide to help?

Comment: would help if you provide some sample code

Comment: here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/kujxsn7z/ , you might want to check the order you fire things. without code its hard to say what is wrong.

Comment: I can get the chart as an image, but I get issues when I add the chart (as an image) to a canvas and try to download it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your not waiting for the img onload to finish. all code needs to be after the onload, try:

```
function turnToImage(chart, totalNum) {
    var pound = '\u00A3';
    var width = $(document).width();
    var height = $(document).height();
    var total = "Total: "+pound+totalNum;
    channels3 = channels2.substring(0, channels2.length - 1);
    var canvasText = total + " | Type: " + allNone + " | Channels: " + channels3 + " | Grouped By: " + grouping + " | Cumulative: " + cumulative + " | Dates: " + startDate + " - " + endDate;

    var canvas = '<canvas id="chartImage" width="'+width+'" height="'+height+'"></canvas>';
    $("#canvasHolder").html(canvas);

    var c = document.getElementById("chartImage");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.font = "15px Helvetica";

    img = new Image();
    img.src = chart;
    img.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 20);

        ctx.fillText(canvasText, 10, 15);

        var dt = c.toDataURL('image/png');

        window.open(dt);

        $("#canvasHolder").html("<img src='"+dt+"'>");
    }

}
```

Although I don't think the open new window method will work, the browser might block it, you might need a workaround.

Comment: I'm now struggling to make it download automatically, any tips?

Comment: make the data url ( c.toDataURL('image/png') ) after the chart is generated. Then when the user clicks just open the result in a window.

Comment: I've got that, I want to image to automatically download

Comment: what is it doing now?

Comment: Like you said, it opens the image on a new tab

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527713/force-browser-to-download-image-files-on-click