# html5 <a download> force "save as" dialogue

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <a href="https://www.google.com.ua/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" download> download</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hello! Any suggestions to force save-as dialogue for image w/o .htaccess?

Comment: Hey, you misspelled "as" in your title. Might want to fix that, someone will probably flag your question if you don't.

Comment: @AnishGoyal ty, i'm a bit sleepy

Comment: @JaromandaX it's looks like too heavy solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [force browser to download image files on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527713/force-browser-to-download-image-files-on-click)

Comment: This is a browser (chrome ? ) feature. Your user may configure it as he wishes. https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvOD8.png And even FileSaver.js can't do anything about it...

Comment: @Kaiido probably it is. When i unselect this option, even `<a download>` goes well.

Comment: @УнгамистДолматов, yes sure, but you can't control this behavior on your users' browsers, it's their choice, and we have no way to force it...

Comment: Fair enough - I take it all back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a browser (chrome ? ) feature.

Your users may configure it as they wish.

[image: Screenshot of Chrome's settings]

Neither you nor even FileSaver.js can do anything about it...

Answer (score -1):

Adapted from the post:
[force browser to download image files on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527713/force-browser-to-download-image-files-on-click)

Since the html5 'download' attribute will still only work for compliant browsers. 
(As per @RichardParnaby-King's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17527821/3951987))

You can try:

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = 'images.jpg';
link.download = 'Download.jpg';
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
```

(Thanks to @DrowsySaturn's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21210576/3951987))
It's also worth mentioning that since it's JS, some older browsers won't support this.

Since browsers each have their own way of handling links, generally browsers will aim to display an image if specified by a URL on an  tag and not automatically download them. This is aimed to be rectified with the [download attribute in HTML5](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp) but obviously some browsers wouldn't have yet implemented (and some may never).

PS: Try search for your question first to prevent duplicates!

Comment: Did you tried to test it? https://jsfiddle.net/ezsk8bvb/ still does not runs "save as" dialogue.

Comment: @УнгамистДолматов what browser & version are you using? https://jsfiddle.net/ezsk8bvb/1/ works for me (Chrome 57.0.2987.110 (64-bit)).

Comment: You are confusing the question of whether a particular link represents a file to be downloaded, with that of whether the app can force the "Save as..." dialog (which it can't).

Answer (score -1):

The most reliable approach is to force it on the server side.

For your convenience, the browser will automatically handle particular content in specific ways. In particular, the browser will automatically handle an image by displaying it inline, which is what you are trying to avoid.

How does the browser know that it’s an image, as opposed to some other content. The server sends a header to say so. In the case of **png** image, the server sends something like this:

`Content-Type: image/png`.

The trick is to get the server to also send a preferred method of handling the content. In your case you need a header like this:

`Content-disposition: attachment; filename=…`

This will tell the browser to download it.

A simple PHP script to do this would be something like this:

```
//  assuming png
$filename=@_GET['filename'];
$data=file_get_contents($filename);
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
header('Content-type: image/png');
print $data;
```

Answer (score -1):

Solved by [@Kaiido](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42967050/html5-a-download-force-save-as-dialogue#comment73028273_42967050)'s comment:

> This is a browser (chrome ? ) feature. Your user may configure it as
>   he wishes. i.stack.imgur.com/BvOD8.png And even FileSaver.js can't do
>   anything about it...

Most chrome-based browsers (Opera in my case) has this option enabled by default.

Comment: Cool, glad you solved it. If that option was enabled by default though, why didn't it ask you to save before?