# Force Download Images with Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, download, google-street-view

I have a list of public links of Google streetview images similar to this

"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=40.720032,-73.988354&fov=120&heading=120&pitch=20&key=AIzaSyC6UbcmFhZkX2q-3EyuHxl56e4zaF3L0y4"

I want to automate downloading of these image files to my computer using Javascript. Is there any Javascript library I can use for this task?

Comment: It would help to post the code you've attempted so far and which part of your program you're struggling with.

Comment: Actually, I haven't found any useful resource/documentation to attempt coding. I just need to know if there's any javascript library I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a download link you can use a link with the "download" attribute (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17527821/5181367)):

```
<a href="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=40.720032,-73.988354&fov=120&heading=120&pitch=20&key=AIzaSyC6UbcmFhZkX2q-3EyuHxl56e4zaF3L0y4" download>Download</a>
```

For an automatic download you can use a script (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21210576/5181367)):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=40.720032,-73.988354&fov=120&heading=120&pitch=20&key=AIzaSyC6UbcmFhZkX2q-3EyuHxl56e4zaF3L0y4';
    link.download = 'Download.jpg';
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
</script>
```