# Strange response S3 getObject

Tags: javascript, ajax, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to get a file from S3 with Javascript but I'm getting a very strange code, check the image after code

```
      AWS.config.update({
        'accessKeyId': 'XXX',
        'secretAccessKey': 'XXX',
        'region': 'us-east-1'
      });
      var s3 = new AWS.S3();
      var s3Params = { Bucket: "mybucket", Key: "path/photo-515169.jpeg"}
      const url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', s3Params)
      $.ajax({
          url: url,
          success: function(url){
            console.log(url)
          }
      })
```

Here's the console.log:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6E8L.png)

Comment: It looks like you are simply getting the binary image back. What would you expect instead?

Comment: I just want force the download the image

Comment: You want the user who visits your site to get a download dialog for that image?

Comment: Well, this is inside a click function, so I want users download the image directly without preview it at the browser.

Comment: Perhaps related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527713/force-browser-to-download-image-files-on-click

Comment: This was the first idea but download attribute doesn't work if image is on other domain