# Downloading a png image when click on it Bootstrap 4 and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to download a picture as soon as I click on it. The picture itself is SVG but I have an URL for a PNG image. I checked and the content disposition is attachment, and yes when I copy the URL directly a download immediately starts.

I am using Bootstrap 4

The function

```
function downloadPNGImage(linkElement) {
    var myDiv = document.getElementById('download-area');
    var myImage = myDiv.children[0];
    let downloadLink = myImage.src + "&format=png";
    linkElement.setAttribute('download', downloadLink);
    linkElement.href = downloadLink;
}
```

And the image itself is:

```
            <div class="col-lg-5 order-first order-md-last img-fluid" id="download-area">
                <img src="https://bananomonkeys.herokuapp.com/image?address=ban_1ttyqinz739g88tteqzyg3hwahg9oxbks8amsywqmim7j4afih7n9d1ssqjf&bg=t"
                    class="loaded" id="generated-monKey" alt="" href="#" onclick="downloadPNGImage(this)" download>
            </div>
```

So when I add "&format=png" this URL is no longer an inline SVG, it is an attached PNG that I would like to download, but for some reason, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify the function a bit:

```
function downloadPNGImage(linkElement) {
    var myDiv = document.getElementById('download-area');
    var myImage = myDiv.children[0];
    let downloadLink = myImage.src + "&format=png";
    linkElement.setAttribute('download', downloadLink);
    linkElement.href = downloadLink;
    linkElement.click();
}
```

modify the onclick handler:

```
onclick="downloadPNGImage(document.createElement('a'))"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `download` attribute won't work on an `<img>` tag you would be better wrapping your image in an `<a>` tag and adding the download attribute to that instead. In your javascript you are adding a .href to an img tag which again won't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I would open new window with generated link. So the code would look like this:

```
function downloadPNGImage(linkElement) {
    var myDiv = document.getElementById('download-area');
    var myImage = myDiv.children[0];
    let downloadLink = myImage.src + "&format=png";
    window.open(downloadLink);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use JS?

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_download

or if you need cross origin:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49886131/9590657

This question is close to your question: [Force browser to download image files on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527713/force-browser-to-download-image-files-on-click)