# How to filter WebImages by a specific attribute?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to write an Program that will automatically make a google-pictures-search and download the first image of the given String.

I'm doing it all with selenium webdriver for Google, but I can change it tho. I tried to filter the results, but the only thinks that appears different to me is the "data-atf"-attribute. I want to download the first, so it should be on zero, but how Can I search after that? Besides the other attributes always change because of the different String that is given.

```
String = "German Shepherd"
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https:/google.com/search?q=" + String + 
"&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEw
 iXlMO0nq_jAhUEzaQKHVVXC50Q_AUIEygE&biw 
 =834&bih=770");



//and then I've got something like this
//wont work because cssSelector is always different
WebElement img = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#selector"));
BufferedImage buffer = ImageIO.read(new URL(img.getAttribute("src")));
ImageIO.write(buffer, "png", new File("image.png"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    driver.close();
}
```

Credits for the second part to: [Save/copy to clipboard image from page by chrome console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52030841/save-copy-to-clipboard-image-from-page-by-chrome-console/52031202#52031202)

I need help most importantly to filter the result and after that helping to download would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter the images to the only those which have `data-atf` attribute the easiest is doing it via [XPath selector](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)

```
//img[@data-atf]
```

alternatively, if you want only children of "Search Results":

```
//h2[text()='Search Results']/parent::*/descendant::img[@data-atf]
```

Of course you can also filter images in Java code using [Stream.filter()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) function

```
List<WebElement> allImages = driver.findElements(By.tagName("img"));
System.out.println("All images #: " + allImages.size());

List<WebElement> imagesWithDataAtf = allImages
        .stream()
        .filter(image -> image.getAttribute("data-atf") != null)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println("Images with data-atf attribute #: " + imagesWithDataAtf.size());
```