# How can i upload a file by using the download link to the file

Tags: javascript, html, css, alfresco

I am setting up a file viewer to work with another web application, and to make it more user friendly instead of making the user download and upload the file themselves, i want to pass the download link to upload(if anyone has experience with alfresco and know how to get the file itself please tell me), is there any way to do that?

Comment: You want to download and the upload the same file to the same server ? Please be more specific...

Comment: I want to use the download link i get from the alfresco server, to upload the file to the viewer

Comment: [please look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49836565/9042437) -impliment it

Comment: On what is the "fileviewer" running, what are you using to write it... My magic bullet is not working

Comment: @Marc the fileviewer is running on node written in javascript, and uses Autodesks API

Comment: @malikaasen You have just to let the user input the download link on your page, pass them to the server, download the file with a http request and then do with the file what you want. I see no problem here

Comment: i've made it somewhat work with the httprequest and will probably be able to do the rest. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the [Alfresco REST API](https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/). Specifically, [getNodeContent](https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/#!/nodes/getNodeContent) allows you to get the content on a node.

This API requires Alfresco 5.2 or higher. If you are using an older version, please specify.

Comment: I got it to work by using getNodeContent, and now need to figure the Autodesk side. Thanks for the help!