# Download remotely stored image

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I'm  working on Angular 6 project and i need to download an image which hosted in AWS S3 (Remotely.I tried below approach and  it didn't work  for me .I have the image URL

```
<a href=" http://localhost/projectName/uploads/3/1535352341_download.png" class="btn clss"
                  target="_self" download>Download</a>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force browser to download image files on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527713/force-browser-to-download-image-files-on-click)

Comment: seems like the above method will only work if you have the image placed in the assets folder

Comment: it seems download doesn't work for cross-origin hrefs as mentioned in this answer.https://stackoverflow.com/a/17527821/1886334 .so it's better to use another approach.may be it will work if you allow cross domain share not sure

Comment: Attach the stacktrace of errors which you are getting it is difficult to find it without knowing what are the cause of your problem instead of knowing your problem.

Comment: @HimanshuSharma there wont be any error it will just load the image in the same tab . the reason is as Madhawa Priyashantha  stated above

Answer (score 1):

Here are a bunch of checks which you should do before trying to access an S3 Object publicly.

1. **Public access must be enabled** on the S3 object.
2. **CORS** must be allowed on the bucket.
3. The object **should open on the browser** if you enter the link to the S3 Image.

The first and second checks can be done from the AWS S3 Console page itself.

If all these three tests pass, then it should work fine, in my opinion. Do reply if you face any errors! :)