# How to save an image and download it in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

I have an application that displays a photo gallery. Under each photo there is a button which, when clicked, is supposed to save the photo on the user's computer. Unfortunately, the photos are saved as an HTML document when downloaded. That is why they cannot be opened after downloading. The photos are stored in a static uploads folder attached to the project using `nodejs`. How do I download a photo so that it is saved in the correct format?

What I have already tried is using the `download` attribute by placing the photo under the `a` tag as here:

`` <a href={file.path} download>download</a>` or `<a href={file.path} download={file.name}>download</a> ``.

I also tried using the `file-saver` module, but with no positive result. With this solution, the image is also saved as an HTML documen:

```
const Gallery = () => {
//
const downloadImage = (file) => {
  saveAs(
    `http://localhost:3000${file.path}`,
     file.name + '.' + file.type
   )
}

//

  return (
    <button onClick={downloadImage(currentFile)} type='button'> download </button>
  )
}
```

In react-router-dom, I don't have the route set so that I can preview the photo directly after clicking on the photo.

Comment: What is the file extension of the photos? From what browser are you downloading?

Comment: Double check the following resource: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_download

Comment: @Wasbeer I tested in Firefox 91 and Chrome 92 and the file extension is .png.

Comment: Did you commit your work when using "<a href={file.path} download>download</a>"? I would be glad to look at it.

Answer (score 2):

i think this can help you, call **download** function then pass **image url**,**image name after download** and **type of image**

```
function toDataURL(url) {
  return fetch(url)
    .then((response) => {
      return response.blob();
    })
    .then((blob) => {
      return URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    });
}

async function download(url, name = "download", type = "png") {
  const a = document.createElement("a");
  a.style.display = "none";
  a.href = await toDataURL(url);
  a.download = name + "." + type;
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  document.body.removeChild(a);
}
```

The code above is adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56041886) by [@Emeric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9753985/emeric).

**code description**

first create temporary link (invisible) and then send request to your server to fetch image data, then set image data as link href that we created and then add link to body, we need virtual click on this link using js finally remove a tag from body

Done, image downloaded...